# Recyclerview items not covering entire screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am struggling with a bug for a couple of days. For some reason, my recycler view items don't cover the entire screen.
Here is the code :

**feed_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.bookally.ui.posts.feed.FeedViewModel" />

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/MainHeading"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/feed"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/feeds_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="28dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="28dp"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_feed" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.addPosts()}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/create_post" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**item_feed.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="post"
            type="com.example.bookally.firebase.PostContent" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/post_border">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/author_profile_picture"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/user_image"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:setProfilePhoto="@{post.authorImageUrl}" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/author_name"
            style="@style/MainHeading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@{post.author}"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/author_profile_picture"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Iqbal Singh" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            style="@style/MainHeading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="@{post.username}"
            android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/author_profile_picture"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/author_name"
            tools:text="\@just_another_boy" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_content"
            style="@style/SubHeading"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="@{post.content}"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username"
            tools:text="Anything random ...." />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/like_btn"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/likes"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/post_image"
            app:likeIcon="@{post.likedBy}" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/likes_no"
            style="@style/MainHeading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/like_btn"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/like_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/like_btn"
            app:likesText="@{post.likes}"
            tools:text="7 Likes" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/comments_no"
            style="@style/MainHeading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:commentsText="@{post.commentsNumber}"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/comment_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/comment_btn"
            tools:text="0 Comments" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/comment_btn"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/comment"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_comment"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/likes_no"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/post_image" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/save_post_btn"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/save_post"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/post_image"
            app:saveIcon="@{post.savedBy}" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/add_friend_btn"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/add_friend"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_friend"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/username"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/author_name" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/post_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/post_imageview_content_description"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/comments_no"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/post_content"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:loadImagesFromFirebase="@{post.postImageUrl}" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**FeedAdapter**

```
class FeedAdapter(private val onClickListener: ClickListener)  : PagingDataAdapter<Post, FeedAdapter.FeedViewHolder>(
    DiffCallback
) {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FeedViewHolder {
        return FeedViewHolder(ItemFeedBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FeedViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val post = getItem(position)

        holder.itemView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.like_btn).setOnClickListener { if (post != null)  onClickListener.onLikeClicked(post)  }
        holder.itemView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.comment_btn).setOnClickListener { if (post != null)  onClickListener.onCommentClicked(post)  }
        holder.itemView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.save_post_btn).setOnClickListener { if (post != null) onClickListener.onSavePostClicked(post)  }
        holder.itemView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.add_friend_btn).setOnClickListener { if (post != null)  onClickListener.onAddFriendClicked(post)  }

        if (post != null)  holder.bind(post.postContent)
    }

    class FeedViewHolder(private val binding : ItemFeedBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(feed: PostContent) {
            binding.post = feed
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }
    }
```

In the design tab, everything looks fine :
[image: Image of Design Tab]

However, the problem arises in real devices :
[image: Image on Real Device]

However, if I add a view like this, the items cover the entire screen :

```
 <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/like_btn" />
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: do you set width and height in  android:background="@drawable/post_border" ?

Comment: Hi @saeedata, Thanks for replying. No, I don't set width and height in post_border

Comment: about height i khonw your problem is  android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: you should set fixed height or set maxLines but about width I should test your code

Comment: So, if I didn't get it wrong, you suggest I change layout_height of the constraint layout of item_feed.xml ?

Comment: no of this textView   android:id="@+id/post_content"

Comment: I tried giving it fixed height, however, the problem is still there. :( It is quite weird though because if I add another view (please check the updated question), the items cover the entire screen

Comment: did show the height of cell correctly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227546/discussion-between-iqbal-singh-and-saeedata).

Comment: Generally when I see a problem like this, it is in the RecyclerView adapter `onCreateViewHolder()` method. How are you inflating your item views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is here:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FeedViewHolder {
    return FeedViewHolder(ItemFeedBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)))
}
```

Because you are calling the overload of `inflate()` that does not specify a parent view, your item view's layout params are being ignored. Change it to this instead:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FeedViewHolder {
    return FeedViewHolder(ItemFeedBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you problem is

```
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"



<TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_content"
            style="@style/SubHeading"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="@{post.content}"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username"
            tools:text="Anything random ...." />
```

you must set **fixedHeight** or use **maxLines** and set width to match_parent

also remove this line             android:textAlignment="viewStart"